# How can I inherit HTML templates?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm currently using KnockoutJS with its built-in template engine. What I'd like to do is create a master template that other templates can build on. Kinda like a UserControl in .NET but in HTML.

Example:

```
<script id="ParentTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Header">
            <!-- Header Content Here -->
        </div>

        <div class="Separator></div>

        <div class="Body">
            <!-- Body Content Here -->
        </div>

        <!-- more html here... -->

        <div class="Footer">
            <!-- Footer content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="ChildTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="{template: { name: 'ParentTemplate' }}">
        <header>
            ...
        </header>

        <body>
            ...
        </body>

        <footer>
            ...
        </footer>
    </div>
</script>
```

Please ignore the syntax of `ChildTemplate`; I'm just trying to illustrate sending parts to the `ParentTemplate`.

**Please note**: I'm building a pure HTML/JQuery/KnockoutJS single-page application. There is no .NET/PHP/etc. assisting with these templates.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com/) for composition. Its a great framework for what I think you are trying to achieve

Using DurandalJs you would separate out the various parts into individual files

**Shell.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!- usual content -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-bind="compose:'views/parent.html'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Parent.html**

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header" data-bind="compose:'views/header.html'"></div>

  <div class="Separator></div>

  <div class="Body" data-bind="compose:'views/body.html'"></div>

  <!-- more html here... -->

  <div class="Footer" data-bind="compose:'views/footer.html'"></div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you look at the documentation as it is very good and there are a few templates that have the basics already set-up

**EDIT**
just using Knockout you could use

Javascript

```
var details = {
  header: 'this is the Page header',
  details: 'page details go here',
  footer: 'something about the footer goes here'
};
```

**html templates**

```
<script id="ChildTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'ParentTemplate', data: details }"></div>
</script>

<script id="ParentTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Header" data-bind='text: header'></div>

        <div class="Separator></div>

        <div class="Body" data-bind="text: details"></div>

        <!-- more html here... -->

        <div class="Footer" data-bind="text: footer"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

If your header,details and footer contain html markup then I would suggest changing the bindings from text to html so that it renders properly.

Comment: Pure library suggestions should probably be a comment. I'm thinking a full answer would provide a short example of how to actually accomplish what the OP wants.

Comment: yea, fair enough.  I will try and expand on the answer.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to DurandalJS, but this solution forces me to break up the parent into separate templates and joined later, instead of having one parent template where the child template injects parts into it. So you end up with only two physical template. This solutions ends up with 4 or more.

Comment: That's fine. Glad you found DurandalJS useful though.